# How to load all levels using Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My domain model is:

**Book**

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }
}
```

**Store**

```
public class Store
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StoreLocation> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

**StoreLocation**

```
public class StoreLocation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }

    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
}
```

How can include all the levels (and sublevels) of a `Book`?

```
public Book GetBookById(int Id)
{
    return this._DbContext.Books
        .Include(p => p.Stores)
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == Id);
}
```

What i tried?

- `.ThenInclude(p => p.StoreLocation)` doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try [ThenInclude](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html#including-multiple-levels)?

Comment: Yes. When is a `List` in another `List` i cannot include the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it as shown below.

```
  return this._DbContext.Books.Include(p => p.Stores).ThenInclude(q => q.Locations)
                    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == Id);
```

**Note :** Sometimes VS doesn't show intelisence properly.So beware of intellisense :D .One solution may be for that is,close the VS and restart new instance of it.If it doesn't work, just type what you want without relying on the intelisence. After that it compiles and works properly.

Comment: It doesn't work. On the `.ThenInclude(q => q...` it shows me the methos for a list, i suppose the first one.

Comment: according to your models, it should be a list no ? then what is the problem there ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Yes is a List containing another List. I cannot include the second one (Locations). When use `.ThenInclude` i don't have the `Location` poperty. Instead i have the generic methods for a list.

Comment: what did you mean by generic method ? this is your list property no ? `public virtual ICollection<StoreLocation> Locations { get; set; }`.So why can't you use that then ? with your models where I can use like that.why you can't ?

Comment: Yes that property i use. What i'm tring to say is that when i use `.Include(p => p.Stores).ThenInclude(q => q.)` it shows me the `Add`, `All`, `First`, etc. methods. It doesn't show the `Locations` property.

Comment: That is due to `intelisence` issue on the VS.without considering that just type the code which I have shown above and compile it.All will be ok then.Later you can restart the new instance of VS.

Comment: Never saw that coming. Didn't know that you could type that property without intelisense showing it but **it works**. Post your answer so i can mark it please. Thank you.